# Servo doesn't move with fingerprint

Tags: servo

I've a project which i need to make a door open and close using the fingerprint.

I've successfully made fingerprint works just fine it reads and confirm the fingerprints stored in it but the servo doesn't act at all to my confirmed finger print.

```
    #include <Servo.h>
    #include <Adafruit_Fingerprint.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
Servo myservo;

int getFingerprintIDez();
int pos = 0;
int id ();
// pin #2 is IN from sensor (GREEN wire)
// pin #3 is OUT from arduino (WHITE wire)
SoftwareSerial mySerial(A12, A13);
Adafruit_Fingerprint finger = Adafruit_Fingerprint(&mySerial);

// On Leonardo/Micro or others with hardware serial, use those! #0 is green wire, #1 is white
//Adafruit_Fingerprint finger = Adafruit_Fingerprint(&Serial1);

void setup()
{
myservo.attach(10);
while (!Serial); // For Yun/Leo/Micro/Zero/...

Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.println("Adafruit finger detect test");

// set the data rate for the sensor serial port
finger.begin(57600);

if (finger.verifyPassword()) {
Serial.println("Found fingerprint sensor!");
} else {
Serial.println("Did not find fingerprint sensor :(");
while (1);
}
Serial.println("Waiting for valid finger...");
}

void loop() // run over and over again
{
getFingerprintIDez();
delay(50); //don't ned to run this at full speed.

}

uint8_t getFingerprintID() {
uint8_t p = finger.getImage();
switch (p) {
case FINGERPRINT_OK:
Serial.println("Image taken");
break;
case FINGERPRINT_NOFINGER:
Serial.println("No finger detected");
return p;
case FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR:
Serial.println("Communication error");
return p;
case FINGERPRINT_IMAGEFAIL:
Serial.println("Imaging error");
return p;
default:
Serial.println("Unknown error");
return p;
}

// OK success!

p = finger.image2Tz();
switch (p) {
case FINGERPRINT_OK:
Serial.println("Image converted");
break;
case FINGERPRINT_IMAGEMESS:
Serial.println("Image too messy");
return p;
case FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR:
Serial.println("Communication error");
return p;
case FINGERPRINT_FEATUREFAIL:
Serial.println("Could not find fingerprint features");
return p;
case FINGERPRINT_INVALIDIMAGE:
Serial.println("Could not find fingerprint features");
return p;
default:
Serial.println("Unknown error");
return p;
}

// OK converted!
p = finger.fingerFastSearch();
if (p == FINGERPRINT_OK) {
sweep();
Serial.println("Found a print match!");
} else if (p == FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR) {
Serial.println("Communication error");
return p;
} else if (p == FINGERPRINT_NOTFOUND) {
Serial.println("Did not find a match");
return p;
} else {
Serial.println("Unknown error");
return p;
}

// found a match!
Serial.print("Found ID #"); Serial.print(finger.fingerID);
Serial.print(" with confidence of "); Serial.println(finger.confidence);
}

// returns -1 if failed, otherwise returns ID #
int getFingerprintIDez() {
uint8_t p = finger.getImage();
if (p != FINGERPRINT_OK) return -1;

p = finger.image2Tz();
if (p != FINGERPRINT_OK) return -1;

p = finger.fingerFastSearch();
if (p != FINGERPRINT_OK) return -1;



// found a match!
Serial.print("Found ID #"); Serial.print(finger.fingerID);
Serial.print(" with confidence of "); Serial.println(finger.confidence);
return finger.fingerID;





}

void sweep()
{
 for(int pos = 0; pos < 180; pos += 25)  // goes from 0 degrees to 180 degrees
 {                                  // in steps of 1 degree
   myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
   delay(122);                       // waits 122ms for the servo to reach the position
 }

 for(int pos = 180; pos>=1; pos-=25)     // goes from 180 degrees to 0 degrees
 {                                
   myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
   delay(122);                       // waits 122ms for the servo to reach the position
 }
}
```

Comment: please use the `{}` button to format your code

Comment: you said that you verified the operation of the fingerprint reader .....  did you also verify the operation of the servo? ..... what kind of a servo are you using?